# How to use Azure DevOps server (TFS) Predefined Variable in My Ansible Playbook?

Tags: powershell, shell, ansible, ansible-role, azure-devops-server-2019

I want to use Azure DevOps Predefine Variable "**$(Build.SourcesDirectory)**" in My playbook:

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: KBR_MTL361
  tasks:
   - name: copy file
     win_copy:
      src: D:\Web.config
      dest: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

I am running this ansible-playbook using Azure DevOps Pipeline:

[TFS Pipeline Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJgyt.png)

But it is not working

Is there anyone who has any idea how to use the variable in the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your variables as additional args in the **azure-pipelines.yml** like this:

```
    - task: Ansible@0
      inputs:
        ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
        playbookPathOnAgentMachine: 'ansible/tfs_playbooks/install_agent.yml'
        inventoriesAgentMachine: 'file'
        inventoryFileOnAgentMachine: 'hosts.yml'
        args: '--extra-vars "build_source_dir=$(Build.SourcesDirectory) AGENT_URL=$(AGENT_URL)"'
```

Then you can access the variables in your **playbook**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: show debug
    debug:
      msg: "Dir {{ build_source_dir }} agent url {{AGENT_URL}}"
```

Comment: Finally, it's working... Thank you so much @AstraSerg for your great help to achieve my target.

Answer (score 1):

if you look here: https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Parameters-In-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines there is a certain way to pass Pipeline variables to a powershell script, for instance:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $ApiManagementServiceName,
    $ApiManagementServiceResourceGroup
)

$apimServiceName = $ApiManagementServiceName
$resourceGroupName = $ApiManagementServiceResourceGroup

Write-Host "Api Management Service Name: $($apimServiceName)"
Write-Host "Api Management Resource Group Name: $($resourceGroupName)"
```

you are using still powershell you say, so give this a try or try to do something similar that works in your case, for me the above approach works pretty well in standard powershell.

Comment: I am not using PowerShell in my ansible YAML file.
I have also tried with the shell script as well:
Here is the output for the same:
2020-01-16T04:42:40.9212316Z Successfully connected.
2020-01-16T04:42:40.9212941Z sh tfsvariable.sh D:\Agent_1\_work\1\s


I have run the script like: sh tfsvariable.sh $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

Comment: see the msg:

But when I am using this path in my yml file its act like this:

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
2020-01-16T04:32:36.1905719Z 
2020-01-16T04:32:36.2135800Z ok: [MTL361.metatreesystems.com] => {
2020-01-16T04:32:36.2136628Z     "msg": "D:Agent_1_work1s"
2020-01-16T04:32:36.2136981Z }